# call_user_func(array($this, $method), $par) from parent's constructor?

Tags: php, oop

```
class Parent
{

  public function __construct($method) {
    call_user_func(array($this, $method), 1);
  }

}

class Child extends Parent
{

  public function __construct($method) {
    parent::__construct($method);
  }

  protected function call_me_on_construct($par) { 
    echo $par;
  }

}
```

Creating instance of `$child = new Child("call_me_on_construct");`
I want `call_me_on_construct` method to be called. The problem is Parent's constructor know nothing about `$this`. What is better way to do it?

Thank you.

Comment: Instead of `call_user_func()`, you could also do `$this->$method(1)` in this instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It knows about `$this`. The only error in your code is that you use reserved keyword `parent`

```
class Ancestor
{

  public function __construct($method) {
    call_user_func(array($this, $method), 1);
  }

}

class Child extends Ancestor
{

  public function __construct($method) {
    parent::__construct($method);
  }

  protected function call_me_on_construct($par) { 
    echo $par;
  }

}

$c = new child("call_me_on_construct");
```