# How can I call a custom function that is part of a class in PHP (wordpress do_action style)?

Tags: php, wordpress, oop, closures

Wordpress uses hooks and actions for extensibility. A plugin might look something like this:

```
class myLightbox
{
    function __construct()
    {
        add_action('wp_footer',array($this,'my_footer'));
    }

    function my_footer()
    {
        echo '<script src="http://external-site.com/lightbox.js" ></script>';
    }
}
```

If I run that code outside of Wordpress, I'd like the `add_action` to work - even if it just calls the function immediately.

I read these:

- [call_user_func(array($this, $method), $par) from parent's constructor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3939692/call-user-funcarraythis-method-par-from-parents-constructor)**
- [Enqueue a function (like wordpress add_action)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8870387/enqueue-a-function-like-wordpress-add-action)

The second one is fairly close to what I'd like to do, but I don't think it was designed to work with functions that are part of a class.

I tried using `call_user_function` but I'm not sure how to give it the `array($this,'my_footer')` stuff:

```
function add_action($whenToCall,$contextAndFunction=array())
{
    call_user_func($contextAndFunction);
}
```

I also tried this, but as you can tell my OOP isn't great so I'm struggling:

```
function add_action($whenToCall,$contextAndFunction=array())
{
    $function = array_pop($contextAndFunction);
    $context = array_pop($contextAndFunction);

    $context->$function();

}
```

#### Failed test using `minitech`'s suggestion:

```
class myLightbox
{
    function __construct()
    {
        add_action('wp_footer',array($this,'my_footer'));
    }

    function my_footer()
    {
        echo '<script src="http://external-site.com/lightbox.js" ></script>';
    }
}


function add_action($whenToCall,$contextAndFunction=array())
{
    $contextAndFunction();
}


$myLightbox = new myLightbox();
```

Produces:

```
Fatal error: Function name must be a string
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using PHP 5.4, it's already a callable:

```
$contextAndFunction();
```

[Here's a demo.](http://codepad.viper-7.com/UWdDNJ)

Otherwise, `call_user_func` will work as-is.

```
call_user_func($contextAndFunction);
```

[And there's a demo.](http://codepad.viper-7.com/giBwgw)

Comment: doesn't seem to work. updated question to include my test of your example.

Comment: @cwd: What version of PHP are you using? Anyway, try `call_user_method($contextAndFunction[1], $contextAndFunction[0])`. Although... that's been deprecated since PHP **4.1.0**.

Comment: using 5.3.1 on the dev box, later 5.3 (but not 5.4) on the server. that gives me "Deprecated: Function call_user_method() is deprecated" and no output.

Comment: @cwd: Sorry, apparently it only works in PHP 5.4. `call_user_func` is working for me, though... http://codepad.viper-7.com/giBwgw

Comment: Ok, great to know the benefits of 5.4. I think my mistake in 5.3 was actually not using the `text/plain` header (which I usually enable) when testing, lol. So apparently even when I got it working it was showing up blank.